# How to add border to OHAttributedLabel

Tags: ios4

I am using OHAttributedLabel from AliSoftware to add user defined hyperlinks to my UILabels. I need to be able to add borders around my OHAttributedLabel items. Can someone give me code examples on how to do this. The regular myLabel.layer.bordercolor does not work on these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for adding borders you can go with QuartzCore Framework.
Import that framework and use the following code.

```
[[typeTableView layer]setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [[typeTableView layer]setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [[typeTableView layer]setBorderWidth:3];
    [[typeTableView layer]setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

This is how you can give the border,you can give its radius,width and so on.
And do add the quartz core framework first
thanks